# Rollback whole swarm when one service fails

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

Is it possible to rollback another services when only one fails on update with `docker stack deploy`?

For example I have serv1, serv2, serv3. I run `docker stack deploy`,
serv1 and serv2 update without any problems, but then serv3 fails on healthcheck.  Now I want serv1, serv2 and serv3 to rollback to previous version.

Is that possible in docker swarm mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add pinging each other to each service's health check.

So, service 1 health check - ensures service 1 is running, and both service 2 and service 3 is reachable.
For service 2 - ping 1st and 3rd services
For service 3 - ping 2nd and 3rd.

As result, if any of services fails, its restarted, if it fails to ping any of dependent ones, its restarted too.

I encountered analogous issue, so, we added 4th service - the global healthchecker one, that has docker socket mounted from host, and it pinged all services. It was custom and, quite ugly, nodejs script. It pinged/checked each of services it was watching, and if any of them failed, it send `docker service update --force serv1` or something like this to docker socket bound from host machine.